# JMeter Mail Reader Sampler extract from Subsample

Tags: regex, email, jmeter

I'm trying to extract a user Id by a `Regular Expression Extractor` from a `Mail Reader Sampler`'s sub-sub-sample without success.

I don't understand why the `Regular Expression Extractor` won't check the sub-samples of my `Mail Reader Sampler`. Any hint how I can extract the user id?

My Mail Reader Sampler
[image: Mail Reader Sampler]

My Response of the Mail Reader Sampler. The Sub-Sub-Sample actually contains the email as html.
[image: Response of the Mail Reader Sampler]

My Regular Expression Extractor
[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

The email contains a part like this which holds the activation link containing the user id:

```
<span class="link-ref"><a href="https://domain.local:443/account/activate?userId=La21BhmS&token=FefcOrcd7g">https://domain.local:443/account/activate?userId=La21BhmS&token=FefcOrcd7g</a></span>
```

Comment: Try `userId=([^&\n]+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the reply. Your suggested regex didn't work. The variable is still not set after regex evaluation. To me it seems more the Regex Extractor ignores the sub-samples of the Mail Reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular Expression Extractor won't go deeper than 1st level of sub-samples (it will look into `Message 1` only), I would recommend iterating subresults using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and appending the results to the main sampler so you could use the Regular Expression Extractor.

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of your Mail Reader Sampler
2. Make sure you put the JSR223 Post Processor **before** the Regular Expression Extractor
3. Make sure you have [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) in the "Language" dropdown
4. Put the following code into the JSR223 PostProcessor "Script" area

   ```
   StringBuilder aggregateResult = new StringBuilder()
   prev.getSubResults().each {
       aggregateResult.append(it.getResponseDataAsString())
       it.getSubResults().each {
           aggregateResult.append(it.getResponseDataAsString())
           it.getSubResults().each {
               aggregateResult.append(it.getResponseDataAsString())        
           }   
       }
   }
   prev.setResponseData(aggregateResult.toString().getBytes())
   ```

   The above code will append results of the sub-samplers up to 2nd level to the "Mail Reader Sampler" response data and your regular expression will work. See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you! I had do add another layer of iteration because the actual result was within the fourth subResults. I've updated your answer to match my case.